# Return the same values with count in a JSON Array, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My data seems to be like this:

```js
const myObj = {
  "incidents": [{
    "id": 4,
    "fullName": "edsadas",
    "address": "Bagbaguin, Pandi, Bulacan",
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "fullName": "reasdsa",
    "address": "Dalig, Balagtas, Bulacan",
  }, {
    "id": 6,
    "fullName": "dsa",
    "address": "Dalig, Balagtas, Bulacan",
  }],
}
```

My question, how can i return the similar values with count, like this:

```
{
  "Dalig, Balagtas, Bulacan": 2,
  "Bagbaguin, Pandi, Bulacan": 1
}
```

Comment: the `address` key

Comment: There is some difference between same and similar...

Comment: ill edit the question, sorry man

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use the function `reduce`:**

```js
var obj = {  "incidents": [{      "id": 4,      "fullName": "edsadas",      "address": "Bagbaguin, Pandi, Bulacan",    },    {      "id": 5,      "fullName": "reasdsa",      "address": "Dalig, Balagtas, Bulacan",    },    {      "id": 6,      "fullName": "dsa",      "address": "Dalig, Balagtas, Bulacan",    }  ]};
var result = obj.incidents.reduce((a, c) => {
            a[c.address] = (a[c.address] || 0) + 1
            return a;
         }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Using `reduce` and `comma operator`:**

```js
var obj = {  "incidents": [{      "id": 4,      "fullName": "edsadas",      "address": "Bagbaguin, Pandi, Bulacan",    },    {      "id": 5,      "fullName": "reasdsa",      "address": "Dalig, Balagtas, Bulacan",    },    {      "id": 6,      "fullName": "dsa",      "address": "Dalig, Balagtas, Bulacan",    }  ]},         
    result = obj.incidents
                .reduce((a, c) => (a[c.address] = (a[c.address] || 0) + 1, a), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ele, your solution is perfect. It could be even more compact using comma operator. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6oh8qy6/3/)

Comment: Ugh, please don't use the comma operator for this. It does nothing to add clarity to the code.

Comment: @RannieOllit Thank you is also good, but accepting the answer that solved your problem is a better way :)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over them and increment the value every time. If not found just assign `1`

```js
const data = [
  {
     "id": 4,
     "fullName": "edsadas",
     "address": "Bagbaguin, Pandi, Bulacan",
  },
  {
     "id": 5,
     "fullName": "reasdsa",
     "address": "Dalig, Balagtas, Bulacan",
  },
  {
     "id": 6,
     "fullName": "dsa",
     "address": "Dalig, Balagtas, Bulacan",
}];

const count = data.reduce((acc, item) => (acc[item.address] = acc[item.address] ? acc[item.address] + 1 : 1, acc), {});

console.log(count);
```